# excerpt in simple search shows url of file in search results

Tags: simple-search

I'm using the native EE simple search, and I'm using the {excerpt} tag, which displays the correct information on all the search results except for an audio file that pulled up in the results.  For the audio file, it displays the url to the file.  How would I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Channel Preferences, you can select which field is used for the contents of `{excerpt}`.

[image: Screenshot of Channel Preferences]

Comment: i'm unsure, but maybe it is also possible to conditionally display the excerpt. `{if channel_id !="3"}{excerpt}{/if}`.

Comment: Yes, that would work.